# Understanding R non-standard evaluation with tidyverse (ggplot2)

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

The following code yields a plot:

```
ggplot(data = diamonds) + 
  geom_bar(mapping = aes(x = cut, y = after_stat(prop), group = 1))
```

The identifier `prop` is not bound to anything, which is possible in R. It's name is used later and I think it's just more convenient than using quoted strings.

`prop` defines to compute a statistic (proportion), so `y = ...` does not refer to a column name of the date but to the statistic.

`after_stat` delays the evaluation of `prop`, otherwise ggplot would search for a column named `prop`.

Not surprisingly, `?prop` does not help:

```
> ?prop
No documentation for ‘prop’ in specified packages and libraries:
you could try ‘??prop’
```

So far so good.

When I want to investigate what `after_stat` actually does, I get:

```
> after_stat
function (x) 
{
    x
}
<bytecode: 0x9qe2fcx7815>
<environment: namespace:ggplot2>
```

My guess is: Somewhere, an evaluation of `after_stat(prop)` notices that there is a function/thing with a name `after_stat` (instead of an unspecified identifier).

Is this a trick? The "identity" function seems to be of no use otherwise.

Comment: More to review if you look through the source for `ggplot2`: https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/blob/87e9b85dd9f2a294f339d88a353d0c11c851489d/R/aes-evaluation.r.  You'll see other functions like `is_calculated` which check if `after_stat` was called for that argument.

Comment: see the "computed variables" section of the geom you want, `?geom_bar` in your case, these are variables that are computed by ggplot but are accessible to the user, `?aes_eval` has an explanation. these took the form of `..variable..` in earlier versions of ggplot but still work (i guess ggplot finally learned it is bad to break user space)

Comment: `stat_prop` is a variation of `ggplot2::stat_count()` allowing to compute custom proportions according to the by aesthetic defining the denominator : http://ggobi.github.io/ggally/articles/ggally_stats.html#stat-prop-, 
http://ggobi.github.io/ggally/reference/stat_prop.html

Comment: Very helpful, indeed! @Jon Spring thank you for the URL.

Comment: @Park yes, I know, I was more concerned with how it works internally.

Comment: Just nitpicking your title:  this is really `ggplot2` behaviour, probably using other `tidyverse` packages built on R capabilities.  So it would make more sense to use "Understanding `ggplot2` non-standard evaluation" to summarize the question.

Answer (score 4):

Many stat layers (notable exception is `stat_identity()`) have 'computed variables'. You'll see these computed variables documented in the 'Computed variables' section of, for example `?stat_density`. These variables become columns in the working data for a layer, which you can inspect by calling `layer_data(last_plot())` after printing a plot.

The `after_stat()` function, as you pointed out, does nothing to the data. However, because the expressions are captured before being evaluated, ggplot2 can parse the language in the expression to see if the expression contains a call to `after_stat()` (and a few others). The logic of this is in the source code that Jon Spring pointed out.

If you look at the `compute_aesthetics` methods of a layer, you can see that the evaluation of these modified expressions is exempt from evaluation.

```
> geom_point()$compute_aesthetics
<ggproto method>
  <Wrapper function>
    function (...) 
f(..., self = self)

  <Inner function (f)>
    function (self, data, plot) 
{
 # ... omitted for brevity
 calculated <- is_calculated_aes(aesthetics)
 modifiers <- is_scaled_aes(aesthetics)
 aesthetics <- aesthetics[!set & !calculated & !modifiers]
 # ... 
 evaled <- lapply(aesthetics, eval_tidy, data = data, env = env)
 # ...
}
```

For the `after_stat()` function, these aesthetics are evaluated after the statistic has been computed in e.g. the `geom_point()$map_statistic` method. I'm not 100% what is going on here, but it looks like a special environment is build for the evaluation of the modified expressions. I think particular data masks that ensure that the evaluation takes place in the context of the working data and thus have access to the computed variables (rather than global or user-specified layer data which do not).

```r
> geom_point()$map_statistic
<ggproto method>
  <Wrapper function>
    function (...) 
f(..., self = self)

  <Inner function (f)>
    function (self, data, plot) 
{
 # ... omitted for brevity
 new <- strip_dots(aesthetics[is_calculated_aes(aesthetics) | 
        is_staged_aes(aesthetics)])
 if (length(new) == 0) 
        return(data)
 env <- child_env(baseenv(), stat = stat, after_stat = after_stat)
 stage_mask <- child_env(emptyenv(), stage = stage_calculated)
 mask <- new_data_mask(as_environment(data, stage_mask), stage_mask)
 mask$.data <- as_data_pronoun(mask)
 new <- substitute_aes(new)
 stat_data <- lapply(new, eval_tidy, mask, env)
 # ...
}
```